# Google Fit Integration Issue Android

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk, google-fit-api

I am having issues with Google Fit Integration .

I did see it working and now somehow , it doesnt seem to be working .

Verified the Client Id and Client Secret and still issue persists.

Did any of you see issue similar to this.

The issue comes up exactly at the screen where you enable the toggle to get permission from Google Fit , there is a blank screen trying to connect to google fit but end up with no connection to Google Fit and the toggle remains OFF .

Can someone please help me fix this.

Also the info from log cat that I see is

Logcat info

```
2021-11-05 18:53:51.036 7961-13097/org.ghc.android V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 13494602
2021-11-05 18:53:51.045 7961-13097/org.ghc.android D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{ga_event_origin(_o)=auto, ga_previous_class(_pc)=SignInHubActivity, ga_previous_id(_pi)=-8944304530516273355, ga_screen_class(_sc)=GoogleFitLinksActivity, ga_screen_id(_si)=-8944304530516273361}]
2021-11-05 18:53:51.068 7961-13097/org.ghc.android V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2021-11-05 18:53:51.076 7961-13097/org.ghc.android V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2021-11-05 18:53:51.085 7961-13097/org.ghc.android D/FA: Connected to remote service
2021-11-05 18:53:51.088 7961-13097/org.ghc.android V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
2021-11-05 18:53:56.105 7961-13097/org.ghc.android V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: Any advice is apprecaited

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things you could try:

- Ensure that the Fit API is enabled for your Google Cloud project.
- Check your credentials for your Google Cloud project:

  - Ensure that your package name for your credentials matches the sample.
  - Ensure the package name matches the applicationId in the app/build.gradle file.
  - Ensure the Signing-certificate fingerprint is entered correctly.
- From OAuth Consent Screen, add Test users and set User type to external